# JWplayer play PHP script video/audio

Tags: php, jwplayer, readfile

I have an PHP script/page that generates the video/audio file.

```
header('Content-disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: ' . get_mime_by_extension($file_path));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
readfile($file_path);
```

Didn't included the rest because it's not important for this question. The page works perfect and the video is playing when accessing it.

Now I want to use this video/audio in my JWplayer. But I get the error that there is  **no playable source found**. The player works when I add the absolute path of the video file to the JWplayer.

The HTML:

```
<video id="player_358" src="/video/358">Loading</video>
```

The JS:

```
player.setup({
    file: $(this).attr('src'), // --> /video/538.mp4
    html5player: '/media/js/jwplayer.html5.js',
    flashplayer: '/media/swf/jwplayer.flash.swf'
})
```

als tried to add `http://www.domain.com` before the file, but no luck :(

Comment: If you are using JW5, set the provide variable to video, if you are using JW6, set the type variable to mp4.